# sort data per datetime (python, django)

Tags: python, django, pandas, csv, datetime

I am trying to sort my operation by date. The data is formed of couple columns similarly to the one drawn here:

| Company | Income | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 520305 | 03.06.2020 11:20:00 |
| Y | 480305 | 06.06.2020 13:20:00 |

In my case for example, if the user inputs a start date of 10.05.2020 00:00:00 til 05.06.2020 10:00:00. the expected output would be only X.

I hope I am being clear, sorry in advance if I am confusing.

Here is what I did so far:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.FILES['myFile']
        csv = pd.read_csv(file)

        StartDate = request.POST.get('startdate')
        EndDate = request.POST.get('enddate')

        user_start = pd.to_datetime(StartDate)
        user_end = pd.to_datetime(EndDate)

        csv['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(csv['Date'], dayfirst=True)

        montant_init = csv.groupby("Initiateur")["Montant (centimes)"].sum()
        err_count = csv.groupby(['Résultat']).size()

        return render(request, "index.html", {'something': True, 'montant': montant_init, 'error': err_count})


html:

   {% if something %}

        <label for="startdate">Start Date (y.m.d h.m.s):</label>
        <input type="text" name="startdate"><br><br>
        <label for="enddate">End Date (y.m.d h.m.s):</label>
        <input type="text" name="enddate"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">


        <p>{{ montant }}</p>
        <p>{{ error }}</p>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

after these lines

```
user_start = pd.to_datetime(StartDate)
user_end = pd.to_datetime(EndDate)
csv['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(csv['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

you can simply select the data you need

```
csv = csv[(csv['Date'] >= user_start) & (csv['Date'] <= user_end)]
```

and then you can group the data if needed